# Spring MVC Is it possible same @autowired with multiple controllers?

Tags: java, spring

Let's say we got two different controller classes, `AController.java` and `BController.java`.

```
public class AController {
    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;
 }

public class BController {
    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;
 }
```

I wonder if this is okay.

**+ EDIT**

AdminService (Interface)
The top three are from Acontroller, and the other is from BController.
I have no issue with trigger `selectNormalList()` until I create `selectCouponByTerm()`.

```
public interface AdminService {

    List<Member> selectNormalList();
    
    List<Member> selectPartnerList();
    
    List<Coupon> selectCouponByDate(String date);
    
    List<Coupon> selectCouponByTerm(String startDate, String endDate);
}
```

AdminServiceImpl(that implements interface AdminService)

```
@Service
public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService{

    @Autowired
    private static AdminDao adminDao;
    
    @Override
    public List<Member> selectNormalList() {    
        return adminDao.selectNormalList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Member> selectPartnerList() {
        return adminDao.selectPartnerList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Coupon> selectCouponByDate(String date) {
        return adminDao.selectCouponByDate(date);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Coupon> selectCouponByTerm(String startDate, String endDate) {
        return adminDao.selectCouponByTerm(startDate, endDate);
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Short Answer Yes

Comment: Yes - do you have a specific concern?

Comment: After I add BController that takes same @Autowired, I got NullPointerException from AController.

Comment: Show us AdminService class .

Comment: I got the feeling this is more about architecture than the actual question in the title (since that one could have been answered with <1 min trial & error), therefore I voted to close this question since it's likely to be opinion based.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my edited question?

Comment: Add @Controller annonation on the Acontroller and BController

Comment: And why are you declaring AdminDao  as static?

Comment: Sorry, I had @Controller annotation at original source code but didn't put that in the question. My STS suggested me to declare AdminDao as static  (T⌓T)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following approach for the Service class
The way you are structured the logic will lead you to `NULLPointerException`

```
    @Service
    public class AdminServiceImpl implements AdminService{
    
        private AdminDao adminDao;
    
        @Autowired
        private AdminService adminService;
    
         public AdminServiceImpl (AdminDao adminDao){
            this.adminDao= adminDao;
        
 @Override
    public List<Member> selectNormalList() {    
        return adminDao.selectNormalList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Member> selectPartnerList() {
        return adminDao.selectPartnerList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Coupon> selectCouponByDate(String date) {
        return adminDao.selectCouponByDate(date);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Coupon> selectCouponByTerm(String startDate, String endDate) {
        return adminDao.selectCouponByTerm(startDate, endDate);
    }
```

Then in your controllers

```
@Controller
   public class AController {
    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;
 }
   @Controller
public class BController {
    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;
 }
```

Comment: Why would you ever want to autowire the interface?  You're just wiring itself or worse - you're wiring something else into it.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes.

This is the point of dependency injection.  You can inject a dependency into whatever else needs it.

Do pay attention to what you're injecting where, though; if two controllers share common functionality to the degree that they have the same dependencies, *should* they really be two controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is ok. Spring will inject AdminService in both controllers. You have to use @Controller on AController and BController and @Service on AdminService class.